# array_walk & array_combine together is not working for more than 3 fields

Tags: php, sql

I am using the below code to get the Comma separated values from the posted textboxes by using `explode();` function and then `array_walk()` and `array_combine()`.
After that it inserts the data in the table.

It is working for two fields but when I put the 3rd it doesn't work. I'm unable to figure it out. It is not inserting into the table when I put 3 fields.

```
$qs_ansen       = $_POST['answer_en'];
$qs_ansE        = $_POST['ansE'];
$qs_ansur       = $_POST['answer_ur'];

$pc1    =   explode(', ', $qs_ansen);
$pc2    =   explode(', ', $qs_ansE);
$pc3    =   explode(', ', $qs_ansur);

array_walk(array_combine($pc1,$pc2,$pc3), function ($pc5,$pc6,$pc7){
$pc3a           = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select id FROM questions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"));
$pc4a           =   $pc3a['id'];
$test_id        = $_POST['test_id'];
    $answers_query = "INSERT INTO answers (answer, answer_en, qs_id, test_id, ans) 
    VALUES('$pc7', '$pc6', '$pc4a', '$test_id', '$pc5')";
    mysql_query($answers_query);
    //Run sql
});
```

Comment: `array_combine` takes only 2 params , one is keys and other is array

Comment: would you share the solution according to my code?

Comment: tell me what you want to do exactly , how you want to save the data

Comment: everything is fine just here `array_walk(array_combine($pc1,$pc2,$pc3), function ($pc5,$pc6,$pc7){`  $pc1, $pc2, $pc3 it is accepting only 2 and storing the data in the table it is not accepting $pc3 and after putting it in it is not entering the data in the table at all.. i want to process three fields not 2

Comment: merge those three arrays with `array_merge` instead on combine, and remove pc7 from this `function ($pc5,$pc6,$pc7)` so it will be like this `function ($pc5,$pc6)`

Comment: but how i will get the value of 3 fields separately? can u edit in my code and post?